# Android Bitmap Loading performance

Tags: android, bitmap, android-view, android-maps-v2

I am working on an app that requires me to load some bitmaps (to use as marker Icons on a GoogleMap). Each marker needs to be slightly unique though, to be precise, its an X rotated in a number of directions, based on some other data. 
I reckon I can do this two ways, by loading a bitmap from a resource and rotating it on its center to the appropriate angle, then using this, OR by using a canvas, drawing the two lines exactly as I want them, and rendering it as a bitmap.

I can't find any info on the advantages or disadvantages of either approach. I would really appreciate any answer, or anyone who could point me in the direction of one. 
Thank you,
Raymond Macharia.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just a single `Bitmap` and [`MarkerOptions.rotation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#rotation%28float%29) (or `Marker.setRotation` after it was created).

About the two approaches you mentioned: "premature optimization is the root of all evil" - just try one and it you don't see any problems, use it.